# Where does Bertrand Russell discuss mysticism?

Tags: reference-request, wittgenstein, bertrand-russell, anscombe

G. E. M. Anscombe writes in *An Introduction to Wittgenstein's Tractatus* (1971, St Augustine's Press) the following about Wittgenstein's use of the concept of mysticism: (page 170)

> But Wittgenstein took the term over from Russell, who used it in a special way, with reference to an entirely ordinary feeling; one that is well expressed at 6.52: 'We feel that even if all *possible* scientific questions have been answered, still the problems of life have not been touched at all.' And his further comment on this is: 'Of course there then just is no question left, and just this is the answer.'

Anscombe did not cite any text of Russell's where he discusses mysticism which leads me to my question: *Where does Bertrand Russel discuss mysticism?*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From Russel's [Mysticism and Logic](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Mysticism_and_Logic_and_Other_Essays/Chapter_01)

> ## Introduction
>
> Metaphysics has been developed, from the first, by the union and conflict of two very different human impulses, the one urging men towards mysticism, the other urging them towards science. Some men have achieved greatness through one of these impulses alone, others through the other alone: in Hume, for example, the scientific impulse reigns quite unchecked, while in Blake a strong hostility to science co-exists with profound mystic insight.

He outlines the following **characteristics** of mysticism.

> ## 1 Revelatory Intuition
>
> A Reality behind the world of appearance and utterly different from it... regarded with an admiration often amounting to worship; it is ​felt to be always and everywhere close at hand, thinly veiled by the shows of sense, ready, for the receptive mind, to shine in its glory even through the apparent folly and wickedness of Man.
>
> The poet, the artist, and the lover are seekers after that glory: the haunting beauty that they pursue is the faint reflection of its sun. But the mystic lives in the full light of the vision: what others dimly seek he knows, with a knowledge beside which all other knowledge is ignorance.
>
> ## 2 Unity
>
> Belief in unity, and its refusal to admit opposition or division anywhere... In Plato, this impulse is less prominent, being held in check by his theory of ideas; but it reappears, so far as his logic permits, in the doctrine of the primacy of the Good.
>
> Following from the denial of all division  there follows
>
> ## 2.1 Denial of time
>
> ## 2.2 Denial of the reality of evil

## Personal note

I've always had a low opinion of Russell in this regard and am happy to revise it.
(And thanks for asking this question!)

The main thing I would disagree with Russell is in the claim that the impulses to science and mysticism are in opposition. Complementary would have been better.

Comment: What an excellent answer. I would agree completely that he made a terrible mistake by placing science and mysticism in opposition. Worse, he argued against the ideas of Bradley and Spencer Brown, who place this idea of mysticism on a sound philosophical basis. I feel he just didn't like mysticism so didn't want to study it.

Comment: Don't know that I agree with your agreement @PeterJ After all 90% of my answer is Russell verbatim. The remaining 10% half says I am pleased to revise my negative opinion of Russell. The remaining 5% could be expanded... But that's not here yet! About "He didn't like mysticism..." I feel (particularly after discovering this text)  that you are making a mistake. Russell is saying: "Violin is nice... But I really only know piano" which you are hearing as "I don't like violin". I think Anscombe's "an entirely ordinary feeling" for Wittgenstein on mysticism is more objectionable than Russellor W

Comment: I stand by my praise for the answer. It's good because it quotes Russell on the topic. Russell considered himself a philosopher so has no excuse for not studying it. I'd say he's more like a pianist who doesn't like half the keys so doesn't play them and then wonders why his pieces don't work. .

Comment: What is the relationship between metaphysics and mysticism that sees Russell?

Comment: @Starckman Read the paper at the start of the answer and, if you want a fuller answer ask another question. My short one word answer would be Plato — the father of Rationalism and the most mystical of the philosophers of the mainstream western (so called) canon. (Not distinguishing Plato & Socrates)

Comment: So for Russell, metaphysics intrinsically embodies mysticism, which is mixed with a scientific quest

Comment: I'd say it the other way round: metaphysics *inherently* sits at the 3-way junction of spirituality/mysticism, science & philosophy. *Individual* metaphysicians may be partial to one  or two sides. Russell does a v good job of saying: *While I am strongly in the science, philosophy camp, the 3rd end of the triangle exists; and legitimately!* Wittgenstein -- not coincidentally allied to Russell — does likewise: see last para of Tractatus

Comment: But surely Russell was very opposed to mysticism

Comment: That's a misunderstanding (widespread). He disavowed it *personally;* not as a valid *general* human modality. Pls read https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Mysticism_and_Logic_and_Other_Essays/Chapter_01. Russell was no Dawkins or Sam Harris! (And even Harris is a Buddhist; it's just that where he is brazenly schizophrenic, somtimes materialistic sometimes spiritual, BR was a genuine philosopher

Comment: "Russell was no Dawkins or Harris!" I had this understanding, that's why although I looked at "Mysticism and Logic and Other Essays/Chapter 01", I was confused. Thank you very much

Comment: Heh yes Dawkins et al are religious bigots, it's just that their religion is called materialism (modern jargon physicalism) and converting people is their gospel spreading. Russell (Wittgenstein) are real philosophers who can hold calmly in their heads a view contradictory to theirs and have a real dialogue. Such are rare today

Comment: @Starckman Anecdote: I knew a man who knew Russell personally. While walking down the street in England with Russell some music in a church. My friend said *What beautiful music! May we go in?* Russell hesitated for a moment and then demurred *I'd rather not... It evokes feelings in me that I don't know how to deal with*

Comment: But this sentence could be interpreted in many ways... Bertrand Russell was very clear about its opposition to religion, he was even revoked from a position at a New York university because of that